# Is it possible to draw schematic of coordinate transformations with translation and rotations

Tags: diagrams, technical-drawing

I am new to latex and have been fighting my way through my thesis. At the moment, I am trying to draw this with LaTeX.

[image: Coordinate Transform]

If you happen to know how to draw this or if you could direct me to  start, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Hi user28228 :), So what have tried so far and if possible [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) ?

Comment: As @texenthusiast wrote, you should demonstrate that you have researched your own question by posting a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Your picture looks like a good job for the `tikz-3dplot` package...

Comment: I recommend using [Sketch](http://www.frontiernet.net/~eugene.ressler/) for this. The user manual has some good examples for you.

Comment: Only an off topic comment: the movement 1 does not look like a translation.

Comment: Without some examples of what you've tried, this is 'too broad' I'm afraid.